# Apple notification token on off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a quick question. I currently don't have my device with me to test this but really wanted to know if a new token is generated if the push notification in the device is switched off then back on.

I.e does the app send the same token it previously sent or is a new one generated? Would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app will send the same token of the device. The token is a combination of the device id and some more alphanumeric characters are added. This device token is unique to your device. if want to check this put an NSlog and check.